Using `hist` to bin data while grouping with `over`?
Consider the following example:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series(
            "name", ["A", "B", "C", "D"], dtype=pl.Enum(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
        ),
        pl.Series("month", [1, 2, 12, 1], dtype=pl.Int8()),
        pl.Series(
            "category", ["x", "x", "y", "z"], dtype=pl.Enum(["x", "y", "z"])
        ),
    ]
)
print(df)

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ name ┆ month ┆ category │
│ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ enum ┆ i8    ┆ enum     │
╞══════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ A    ┆ 1     ┆ x        │
│ B    ┆ 2     ┆ x        │
│ C    ┆ 12    ┆ y        │
│ D    ┆ 1     ┆ z        │
└──────┴───────┴──────────┘

We can count the number of months in the dataframe that match each month of the year:
from math import inf


binned_df = (
    df.select(
        pl.col.month.hist(
            bins=[x + 1 for x in range(11)],
            include_breakpoint=True,
        ).alias("binned"),
    )
    .unnest("binned")
    .with_columns(
        pl.col.breakpoint.map_elements(
            lambda x: 12 if x == inf else x, return_dtype=pl.Float64()
        )
        .cast(pl.Int8())
        .alias("month")
    )
    .drop("breakpoint")
    .select("month", "count")
)
print(binned_df)

shape: (12, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ month ┆ count │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i8    ┆ u32   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 2     │
│ 2     ┆ 1     │
│ 3     ┆ 0     │
│ 4     ┆ 0     │
│ 5     ┆ 0     │
│ …     ┆ …     │
│ 8     ┆ 0     │
│ 9     ┆ 0     │
│ 10    ┆ 0     │
│ 11    ┆ 0     │
│ 12    ┆ 1     │
└───────┴───────┘

(Note: there are 3 categories "x", "y", and "z", so we expect a dataframe of shape 12 x 3 = 36.)
Suppose I want to bin the data per the column "category". I can do the following:
# initialize an empty dataframe
category_binned_df = pl.DataFrame()

for cat in df["category"].unique():
    # repeat the binning logic from earlier, except on a dataframe filtered for
    # the particular category we are iterating over
    binned_df = (
        df.filter(pl.col.category.eq(cat))  # <--- the filter
        .select(
            pl.col.month.hist(
                bins=[x + 1 for x in range(11)],
                include_breakpoint=True,
            ).alias("binned"),
        )
        .unnest("binned")
        .with_columns(
            pl.col.breakpoint.map_elements(
                lambda x: 12 if x == inf else x, return_dtype=pl.Float64()
            )
            .cast(pl.Int8())
            .alias("month")
        )
        .drop("breakpoint")
        .select("month", "count")
        .with_columns(category=pl.lit(cat).cast(df["category"].dtype))
    )
    # finally, vstack ("append") the resulting dataframe 
    category_binned_df = category_binned_df.vstack(binned_df)
print(category_binned_df)

shape: (36, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ month ┆ count ┆ category │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ i8    ┆ u32   ┆ enum     │
╞═══════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ x        │
│ 2     ┆ 1     ┆ x        │
│ 3     ┆ 0     ┆ x        │
│ 4     ┆ 0     ┆ x        │
│ 5     ┆ 0     ┆ x        │
│ …     ┆ …     ┆ …        │
│ 8     ┆ 0     ┆ z        │
│ 9     ┆ 0     ┆ z        │
│ 10    ┆ 0     ┆ z        │
│ 11    ┆ 0     ┆ z        │
│ 12    ┆ 1     ┆ z        │
└───────┴───────┴──────────┘

It seems to me that there should be a way to do this using over, something like pl.col.month.hist(bins=...).over("category"), but the very first step of trying to do so raises an error:
df.select(
    pl.col.month.hist(
        bins=[x + 1 for x in range(11)],
        include_breakpoint=True,
    )
    .over("category")
    .alias("binned"),
)

ComputeError: the length of the window expression did not match that of the group

Error originated in expression: 'col("month").hist([Series]).over([col("category")])'

So there's some sort of conceptual error I am making when thinking of over? Is there a way to use over here at all?

Here's one approach using Expr.over:
bins = range(1,12)

out = df.select(
    pl.col('month').hist(
        bins=bins,
        include_breakpoint=True
    )
    .over(partition_by='category', mapping_strategy='explode')
    .alias('binned'),
    pl.col('category').unique(maintain_order=True).repeat_by(len(bins)+1).flatten()
    ).unnest('binned').with_columns(
    pl.col('breakpoint').replace(float('inf'), 12).cast(int)
    ).rename({'breakpoint': 'month'})

Output:
shape: (36, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ month ┆ count ┆ category │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ i64   ┆ u32   ┆ enum     │
╞═══════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ x        │
│ 2     ┆ 1     ┆ x        │
│ 3     ┆ 0     ┆ x        │
│ 4     ┆ 0     ┆ x        │
│ 5     ┆ 0     ┆ x        │
│ …     ┆ …     ┆ …        │
│ 8     ┆ 0     ┆ z        │
│ 9     ┆ 0     ┆ z        │
│ 10    ┆ 0     ┆ z        │
│ 11    ┆ 0     ┆ z        │
│ 12    ┆ 1     ┆ z        │
└───────┴───────┴──────────┘

Explanation

The key is to use mapping_strategy='explode'. As mentioned in the docs, under explode:


Explodes the grouped data into new rows, similar to the results of group_by + agg + explode. Sorting of the given groups is required if the groups are not part of the window operation for the operation, otherwise the result would not make sense. This operation changes the number of rows.

(I do not think sorting is required here, but anyone please correct me if I am wrong.)

This would be faster than using df.group_by, but the gain in performance is offset by the need to get back the categories:

Expr.unique with maintain_order=True + Expr.repeat_by + Expr.flatten.



Adding a performance comparison with the method suggested in the answer by @BallpointBen, testing:

over: over, maintaining order + 'category'
over_ex_cat: over, maintaining order, ex 'category' (highlights the bottleneck)
group_by: group_by, not maintaining order + 'category'
group_by_order: group_by, maintaining order + 'category'

I've left out trivial operations like renaming "breakpoint" column and getting the columns in the same order. Script can be found here (updated for second plot below).

Maybe someone can suggest a better way to get back the categories. Otherwise, there does not seem to be too much between the two methods.

Update: performance comparison with suggested answers by @HenryHarback, testing:

over: over, maintaining order + 'category' (= mapping_strategy='explode')
over_join: over, not maintaining order + 'category' (= mapping_strategy='join')
spine: cross join + left join, not maintaining order + 'category'

Not included is the group_by option + select + struct, which has similar performance to group_by compared above (with unnest). Extended the N-range to show spine catching up with, though apparently not overtaking, over, if the df gets really big.


@jqurious: thanks for correcting the typo. I was just adjusting this from a version that still had .explode instead of .flatten. Have not included that one, as it is (understandably) slower. Any ideas on improving performance still?

Yep - sorry, I don't like to interfere with other posts, but I needed to edit to run the example for myself. I think you've covered everything very nicely here. (to my knowledge, at least)

@ouroboros1 Thanks for this answer. I've accepted it because it provides a nice summary of the discussion across answers. I'm wondering: would it be easy for you to provide the code that produces the graphs? That would be useful for the sake of posterity: when people want to compare other methods, or re-run the comparisons with later versions of polars.

@bzm3r The link is in the answer ("script can be found here").

Here's my suggestion: group by month and category to compute the actual statistics. Then left-join with a blank output frame and fill nulls with zero for output formatting.
stats = df.lazy().group_by("month", "category").len()
blank = (stats
    .group_by("category")
    .agg(month=pl.int_range(1, 13, dtype=pl.Int8))
    .explode("month"))
out = (blank
    .join(stats, on=["category", "month"], how="left")
    .with_columns(pl.col.len.fill_null(0).alias("count"))
    .collect())


I think this is a nice solution because I do not have to bother with hist, which doesn't seem well suited for discrete data. I am not sure if I should accept it as the answer only because my question is currently geared towards over and hist. I am also not sure if I rewriting the question is a good thing. Maybe it would be better to make a separate question about how to create the binned stats in the first place, and then leave this question to deal with the fact that mapping_strategy="explode" is the right move with over.

I believe the complication comes as a result of the fact that .hist changes the number of rows. A workaround is to use mapping_strategy="join" to keep the category together with the binned data, or consider other approaches (shown below).
I will create a github issue on the Polars repo to see if .over can be supported with .hist. Hopefully it can be.
First, we can simplify the first example (without over) substantially.
Main things here are:

avoid map_elements, which iterates over each row and prefer the Polars API. In this case replace works to replace inf with 12, and there is also pl.when as another option to do if statement style logic
you are doing with_columns followed by drop then select. In this (any many) cases, you can just replace this with a single select. select can do expressions like in with_columns, and whatever isn't selected is dropped

binned = pl.col("month").hist(bins=range(1, 12), include_breakpoint=True)
df.select(
    month=binned.struct["breakpoint"].replace(float("inf"), 12).cast(pl.Int8),
    count=binned.struct["count"],
)

And now for the solution with over. I note that this does seem like a workaround / not ideal, given that duplicate rows need to be created, but it does work.
binned = pl.col("month").hist(bins=range(1, 12), include_breakpoint=True)

(
    df.select(
        "category",
        binned.over("category", mapping_strategy="join"),
    )
    # After the select, we still have 4 rows, with a list of 12 structs
    # in each row in the new "month" col (the output of `hist`)
    .explode("month")
    # After the explode, we now have 48 rows (too many), with the two rows for
    # category "x" being duplicated. So, remove the duplicates.
    # This is what makes the solution seem like a workaround tbh.
    .unique()
    # After the unique, we have 36 rows (the desired amount), so proceed as above
    .select(
        (
            pl.col("month").struct["breakpoint"]
            .replace(float("inf"), 12)
            .cast(pl.Int8)
            .alias("month")
        ),
        pl.col("month").struct["count"],
        "category",
    )
)

Another popular option (which is what I'd personally recommend) is to build a "spine" with all possible values, then left join the counts to that, filling nulls with 0
keys = ["month", "category"]
(
    # The spine is all months, combined with all unique categories
    pl.select(month=pl.int_range(1, 13, dtype=pl.Int8))
    .join(df.select(pl.col("category").unique()), how="cross")
    # Then left join the counts per month and category
    .join(df.group_by(keys).agg(count=pl.len()), on=keys, how="left")
    .with_columns(pl.col("count").fill_null(0))
)

Or finally, if you do the hist grouped by category, it is not too hard to adapt the first code snippet I provided
(
    df.group_by("category")
    # This gets you a list of 12 structs per category
    .agg(pl.col("month").hist(bins=range(1, 12), include_breakpoint=True))
    .explode("month")
    .select(
        "category",
        (
            pl.col("month").struct["breakpoint"]
            .replace(float("inf"), 12)
            .cast(pl.Int8)
            .alias("month")
        ),
        pl.col("month").struct["count"],
    )
)


Thank you for this solution. The "spine" method also seems much nicer to me (and is not dissimilar in idea to @orlp's answer. I think it's unfortunate that my original answer is couched in terms of over and hist, because I think the solution here is to not use over or hist. I am debating whether I should re-write this question.

Well, you can do it with groupby explode, but I don't know how efficient it is.
df.group_by("category").agg(
    # one row per category with the whole list as the element
    pl.col.month.hist(
        bins=[x + 1 for x in range(11)],
        include_breakpoint=True,
    )
).explode("month").unnest("month").with_columns(
    pl.col("breakpoint").replace(float("inf"), 12.0).cast(int)
)

over is like transform in pandas in that it keeps the original identities of the rows, so it would be odd to to use it here — the operation you're trying to do is groupby-agg, with no connection back to the original table rows. (That said I'm not sure why over doesn't do something here; it seems odd that it fails.)
